# Google Colab) How can I get all colab's cells into .ipynb file in cell command line?

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

#### Is there any way to save current colab page into .ipynb file in cell command line?

I need to upload current colab .ipynb file to my web server, but I can't upload ***downloaded colab .ipynb file*** directly from my web page, because it's blocked due to network security issue.

Also, users ( who upload the .ipynb file ) are not familiar with extra settings **like mounting google Drive to colab**.

**So, if I have colab codes like below,**

---

#### numeric variables

```py
a = 3
b = 4
a + b, a - b
```

#### string variables

```py
c = 'hello'
d = 'python'
```

---

**I need to save this whole code into .ipynb file** and send it to my web server inside colab code cell.

If I can make the .ipynb file, then sending it to my server is not a problem.

TIA.

Comment: If I understand it correctly You have a colab session open. If so you can download it as .ipynb file. File->Download->Download .ipynb

Comment: Yes, I can download it. 

But users can't upload that file directly through my web page because it's blocked due to security issue.

So, I have to figure out the way to send current colab code(as .ipynb file) to my web server inside colab